# How to get Access Token without Instagram Tester Account in "Instagram Basic Display API"

Tags: instagram-api

I'm Using "Instagram Basic Display API", I have created WordPress Plugin which can generate access token and can also refresh access token. But its only Working With Instagram Tester Account.

I can't understand how my plugin can generate access token for all users, Like this https://wordpress.org/plugins/instagram-feed/ plugin can do.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway in order for your app to get access tokens you should have Instagram Developer account where you should register your application and get the secrets you need to receive tokens. That's how oauth flow works.